# How to merge a Group of records in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Consider the following table,

```
Name    | Subject_1    | Marks_1    | Subject_2    | Marks_2    |
Tom     | Maths        | 90         |              |            |
Tom     |              |            | Science      | 50         | 
Jon     |              |            | Science      | 70         |
Jon     | Maths        | 60         |              |            |
```

How do I get the following result

```
Name    | Subject_1    | Marks_1    | Subject_2    | Marks_2    |
Tom     | Maths        | 90         | Science      | 50         |
Jon     | Maths        | 60         | Science      | 70         |
```

Tried forms of `GROUP BY` but did not get correct result, Maths will always come under Subject_1 and Science under SUbject_2.

Comment: What's expected to happen if Tom has two maths classes. And if Jon also has History?

Comment: Only single entry for a subject will be available per person in the table and assuming there are only two subjects

Comment: And if new class (History) is found?

Comment: Then we will have a Subject_3 for that

Comment: I can't understand why you're having separate columns for the subjects. Why can't you simply have the columns `Subject` and `Marks`?

Comment: This is how the data is available to me,not my own design, I know its absurd but that's how it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- **MAX**
- **GROUP BY**

```
SQL> SELECT NAME,
  2    MAX(subject_1) subject_1,
  3    MAX(marks_1) marks_1,
  4    MAX(subject_2) subject_2,
  5    MAX(marks_2) marks_2
  6  FROM t
  7  GROUP BY name;

NAME SUBJECT_1    MARKS_1 SUBJECT_2    MARKS_2
---- --------- ---------- --------- ----------
Jon  Maths             60 Science           70
Tom  Maths             90 Science           50

SQL>
```

On a side note, you need to think about your **table design**. You could only have 3 columns, `name, subject, marks`.

If you want to have **separate columns** in the same table, then you should have them as a **single row** for each student. And when you have a new subject for the student, then **update** the row for that student, instead of adding a new row.

Comment: @jarlh No, it was a copy/paste typo. Removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select maths.name,maths.subject_1,maths.marks_1,sci.subject_1,sci.marks_2 
from mytable maths,(select * from mytable where subject_2 is not null) sci 
where maths.name=sci.name
and maths.subject_1 is not null;
```